# Calculating real width of object using euclidian norm

Tags: java, android, opencv

Im trying to calculate the real width of an object in cm using opencv. Following is my code. For some reason, the width is not exact.

```
public static void drawContours(Mat image, ArrayList<MatOfPoint> contours){
        //ArrayList<MatOfPoint> contourList = getContoursLargerThan(contours, 1000);
        //Random random = new Random();

        if(contours != null && contours.size()>0) {
//            for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {
//                Imgproc.drawContours(image, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(255,0,0),3);//random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256)),3);
//            }
            for (MatOfPoint temp : contours) {
                Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(temp);
                Point p1 = new Point(rect.x, rect.y);
                Point p0 = new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height);
                double realWidthInCm = sqrt( (p1.x-p0.x)*(p1.x-p0.x) + (p1.y-p0.y)*(p1.y-p0.y) );
                Log.d(TAG,"Real wiidth " +realWidthInCm);
                Imgproc.rectangle(image, p1, p0,new Scalar(0,255,0),2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Im trying to calculate it by using euclidian norm. what am I missing? How can I get the  real width ?

Comment: You cannot get the real width, because you are processing an digital image and have shown no info on camera calibration. You need to calibrate the camera using some reference object with known dimensions, then you can find the real world dimensions of target object, by analysing the dimensions of reference object.

Comment: May i know how do i calibrate it to some reference object?

Comment: You take a picture from an object with known size. Lets say an object with a width in mm. Then you count the number of pixels representing this width. Then you divide your width by the number of pixels., so the dimension is mm/px. If you found your contour and compute the width, you multiply this width by your scale factor. Viola you got your width in mm or cm..

Comment: Thank you... any examples using opencv will help a lot

Comment: Have you some image tool line irfanview, gimp ,imagej etc. Available? It would be easier to get the scaling factor without opencv. Just take a picture, open it an an image viewer and read out the distance in pixels. Then hardcode the value in your application. (If your settings do not change).

Comment: Yes I have gimp... May I know the necessity to calculate scale factor please.. Is scale factor  specific to each devices and varies on each device?

Comment: Your scale factor is your connection from pixel to metric units. This depends on your device. If you have two devices with different sensor resolutions and different lenses, you get different scales factors for each device. So if you want to perform some measurment you always need to calculate your scaling factor. Just define or print or buy a well defined object, place it under the camera and "calibrate". If you need to do it often, you should program a function for that in opencv.

Comment: thank you.. am i using the current formula to get width

Comment: I used to above code to measure the width of macbook air. Im getting the width as 534 –

Comment: This is the model that Im measuring support.apple.com/kb/sp631?locale=en_US

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just to avoid confusion: You ask for the width but compute the diagonal. I'm assuming you actually want the diagonal and do not get the expected result. This would be because the library does not measure size in centimeters. It cannot do this as the size the object will appear depends on your display device. To adjust the value you are getting you need to multiply by a scale factor that is specific to your screen/display. For example if `realWidthInCm` is 3cm but you observe a width/diagonal of 2cm then a scale factor of `2/3` should correct your result.

If you are working with pixels you may want to use [this](http://www.unitconverters.net/typography/pixel-x-to-meter.htm) to convert to meters.

Comment: should i multiply the result with 2/3 to get the result?

Comment: Those numbers were just an example. You need to multiply the result by a scale factor of `expectedResult/realWidthInCm`. I assume you know or can measure the `expectedResult`.

Comment: May I know how scale factors affects the actual width and height calculation  please?

Comment: Is scale factor device specific?

Comment: Yes, it can vary e.g. with screen resolution or imagine you are using a beamer, then it will vary with its distance to the wall you are projecting onto.

Comment: thank you... am i using the current formula to get the width?

Comment: I used to above code to measure the width of macbook air. Im getting the width as 534

Comment: This is the model that Im measuring https://support.apple.com/kb/sp631?locale=en_US

Comment: expectedResult in cm or in?